# Linear chart for different variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I am trying to figure out why all of my data points are grouped up on the y-axis of my graph (see image below). I am trying to do multiple plots with different variables. How can I separate the values on the y-axis? Also is it possible to show the dates every quarter on the x-axis instead of showing it every year?

I am fairly new to R so your help is much appreciated

Code :

```
library(ggplots)
library(xts)
beta<-as.data.frame(beta)
beta[,"Date"]<- as.Date(beta[,"Date"])
beta<- xts(beta,order.by=beta[,"Date"])
autoplot(beta,facets=Series~.)+ geom_point() + theme_bw()
```

Data set:

```
                Size           Value
2013-01-01   0.032715590    -0.729988962
2013-02-01   0.029004454    -0.720470432
2013-03-01  -0.005376306    -0.774927763
2013-04-01  -0.065253538    -0.832884912
2013-05-01  -0.132726778    -0.805900000
2013-06-01  -0.094694083    -0.693202747
2013-07-01  -0.067636417    -0.540439590
2013-08-01  -0.080754396    -0.523916099
2013-09-01  -0.046787938    -0.633682670
2013-10-01  -0.039442980    -0.527533014
2013-11-01   0.007652725    -0.602841925
2013-12-01   0.012766257    -0.562559325
2014-01-01   0.005465503    -0.590979360
2014-02-01   0.033734341    -0.500183338
2014-03-01   0.036242236    -0.458877891
2014-04-01   0.085039855    -0.370762659
2014-05-01   0.120012885    -0.361754453
2014-06-01   0.146198534    -0.291407100
2014-07-01   0.147598628    -0.393385963
2014-08-01   0.173900895    -0.384568303
```

Image:

[image: Multivariate Plot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of problem is generally a matter of [Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format).

```
library(tidyverse)

beta %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c(Size, Value),
    names_to = "Variable",
    values_to = "Values"
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date, Values, color = Variable)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "3 month", date_labels =  "%b %Y") +
  facet_grid(Variable ~ .) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60, hjust=1))
```

[image]

**Data**

```
beta <- read.table(text = "
Date                Size           Value
2013-01-01   0.032715590    -0.729988962
2013-02-01   0.029004454    -0.720470432
2013-03-01  -0.005376306    -0.774927763
2013-04-01  -0.065253538    -0.832884912
2013-05-01  -0.132726778    -0.805900000
2013-06-01  -0.094694083    -0.693202747
2013-07-01  -0.067636417    -0.540439590
2013-08-01  -0.080754396    -0.523916099
2013-09-01  -0.046787938    -0.633682670
2013-10-01  -0.039442980    -0.527533014
2013-11-01   0.007652725    -0.602841925
2013-12-01   0.012766257    -0.562559325
2014-01-01   0.005465503    -0.590979360
2014-02-01   0.033734341    -0.500183338
2014-03-01   0.036242236    -0.458877891
2014-04-01   0.085039855    -0.370762659
2014-05-01   0.120012885    -0.361754453
2014-06-01   0.146198534    -0.291407100
2014-07-01   0.147598628    -0.393385963
2014-08-01   0.173900895    -0.384568303
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi Rui, I keep getting error undefined columns selected "Size". I do not know why, tried replacing it by beta[,c("Size","Value")] but I still get the same error.

Comment: @Fran The code in my answer is *before* coercing to a `xts` object, see what's the output of `str(beta)`.

Comment: @Fran If you already have a `xts` object, use `fortify(beta) %>% etc` and in `ggplot(aes(Date, etc))` change `Date` to `Index`. The rest of the code should be the same.

Comment: It was executed before xts, when running str(beta) I get a Data Frame :  $ Size                 : num  0.03272 0.029 -0.00538 -0.06525 -0.13273

Comment: @Fran In cases like those, try ending and restarting the R session, it many times works.